# Best iterative way to calculate the fundamental matrix of an absorbing Markov Chain?

Tags: algorithm, math, sparse-matrix, markov-chains

I have a very large absorbing Markov chain. I want to obtain the fundamental matrix of this chain to calculate the [expected number of steps before absortion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Expected_number_of_steps). From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705733/best-way-to-calculate-the-fundamental-matrix-of-an-absorbing-markov-chain) I know that this can be calculated by the equation

(I - Q)t=1

which can be obtained by using the following python code:

```
def expected_steps_fast(Q):
    I = numpy.identity(Q.shape[0])
    o = numpy.ones(Q.shape[0])
    numpy.linalg.solve(I-Q, o)
```

However, **I would like to calculate it using some kind of iterative method similar to the power iteration method** used for calculate the [PageRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank#Iterative). This method would allow me to calculate an approximation to the expected number of steps before absortion in a mapreduce-like system.

**¿Does something similar exist?**

Comment: Have you looked at iterative solvers for systems of linear equations like GMRES? They provide some error estimates to check how many iterations you need. Python provides them in [`scipy.sparse.linalg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres)

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood your question! Have you looked at the [Neumann series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Fundamental_matrix) of the fundamental matrix? It might be possible to approximate the inverse using only a limited number of summands from the power series

Comment: Thanks for your comments @TobiasRibizel. I think that the Neumann series is not what I am searching because it would imply to multiply the matrix several times. However, if I understand correctly the GMRES algorithm, this solution might be parallelized in a per-component basis.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sparse matrix, check if [scipy.spare.linalg.spsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve) works. No guarantees about numerical robustness, but at least for trivial examples it's significantly faster than solving with dense matrices.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
import scipy.sparse.linalg as spla

def example(n):
    """Generate a very simple transition matrix from a directed graph
    """
    g = nx.DiGraph()
    for i in xrange(n-1):
        g.add_edge(i+1, i)
        g.add_edge(i, i+1)
    g.add_edge(n-1, n)
    g.add_edge(n, n)
    m = nx.to_numpy_matrix(g)
    # normalize rows to ensure m is a valid right stochastic matrix
    m = m / np.sum(m, axis=1)
    return m

A = sp.csr_matrix(example(2000)[:-1,:-1])
Ad = np.array(A.todense())

def sp_solve(Q):
    I = sp.identity(Q.shape[0], format='csr')
    o = np.ones(Q.shape[0])
    return spla.spsolve(I-Q, o)

def dense_solve(Q):
    I = numpy.identity(Q.shape[0])
    o = numpy.ones(Q.shape[0])
    return numpy.linalg.solve(I-Q, o)
```

Timings for sparse solution:

```
%timeit sparse_solve(A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 ms per loop
```

Timings for dense solution:

```
%timeit dense_solve(Ad)
1 loops, best of 3: 216 ms per loop
```

Like Tobias mentions in the comments, I would have expected other solvers to outperform the generic one, and they may for very large systems. For this toy example, the generic solve seems to work well enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrew, however I am searching for a method that could be calculated in parallel for all the elements of the solution. Following the GMRES method proposed by Tobias I found other iterative methods like the [Jacobi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method) that could fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I arraived to this answer thanks to @tobias-ribizel's suggestion of using the [*Neumann series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series). If we part from the following equation:

[image: t=(I-Q)^-1 1]

Using the Neumann series:

[image: t=sum_0_inf(Q^k)1]

If we multiply each term of the series by the vector **1** we could operate separately over each row of the matrix **Q** and approximate successively with:

[image: t=sum_0_inf(Q*Q^k-1*1)]

This is the python code I use to calculate this:

```
def expected_steps_iterative(Q, n=10):
    N = Q.shape[0]
    acc = np.ones(N)
    r_k_1 = np.ones(N)
    for k in range(1, n):
        r_k = np.zeros(N)
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                r_k[i] += r_k_1[j] * Q[i, j]
        if np.allclose(acc, acc+r_k, rtol=1e-8):
            acc += r_k
            break
        acc += r_k
        r_k_1 = r_k
    return acc
```

And this is the code using Spark. This code expects that Q is a RDD where each row is a tuple (row_id, dict of weights for that row of the matrix).

```
def expected_steps_spark(sc, Q, n=10):
    def dict2np(d, sz):
        vec = np.zeros(sz)
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            vec[k] = v
        return vec
    sz = Q.count()
    acc = np.ones(sz)
    x = {i:1.0 for i in range(sz)}
    for k in range(1, n):
        bc_x = sc.broadcast(x)
        x_old = x
        x = Q.map(lambda (u, ol): (u, reduce(lambda s, j: s + bc_x.value[j]*ol[j], ol, 0.0)))
        x = x.collectAsMap()
        v_old = dict2np(x_old, sz)
        v = dict2np(x, sz)
        acc += v
        if np.allclose(v, v_old, rtol=1e-8):
            break
    return acc
```